# How to send a HTML string from Javascript to Flask (python)?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I want to send a html script to a python Flask route. It can be content of an html page (with tags and text content).

Here is the javascript portion:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/process/" + htmlstring;  
xhr.open('GET', url, false);
xhr.send();
var retrievedtext = xhr.responseText; //This will be returned by Flask
```

The flask portion of the code is:

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/clean/<source_code>', methods=['GET'])
def process_html_code(source_code):
    //do processing
    return result
```

However, I always get 404 error when sending html as it is not allowed. What is a good approach to be able to send html to flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same route in your Javascript code as you defined in your Python code.

In your flask app you defined a route

`/todo/api/v1.0/clean/<source_code>`

But in your Javascript code you try to send a request to

`http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/process/`

That doesn't fit. Change your url in the Javascript code according to the defined route:

```
var url = "http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/clean/" + htmlstring;
```

This works.